# Which typeface is used in scrartcl?

Tags: fonts, typography

Can somebody tell me which typefaces uses this document?

```
\documentclass[twoside,parskip=half]{scrartcl}
```

I think the serif one it's Times but I'm not sure about it. No idea which font is the sans-serif used for the main titles.

Comment: That line does not set any special fonts, so it should just use the Computer Modern family ... unless, of course, that is part of a larger `.tex` file that you haven't shared with us.  There are many ways to change which fonts a document uses; but it is rarely the `\documentclass` line that makes the decision.

Comment: The font is Computer Modern Roman for the text and Computer Modern Sans for the headings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It uses the standard `Computer Modern` fonts if you don't change the font somewhere else.
If you want to find out which fonts are used in the final `pdf` you can look in the pdf properties which for example the `Adobe Reader` /`Acrobat` provide.